# PagedDatasource for gridview paging

Tags: asp.net, gridview, paging, custompaging

I am using PagedDataSource for gridview's custom paging. Here is the code:

```
PagedDataSource dataSource = new PagedDataSource();

int virtualRowCount = Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TotalRows"]);
dataSource.AllowCustomPaging = true;
dataSource.PageSize = 15;

dataSource.VirtualCount = virtualRowCount;
dataSource.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;


gvTaxPayerLoginDetail.DataSource = dataSource;
gvTaxPayerLoginDetail.DataBind();
```

I am returning the "totalrows" from my Stored procedure (which is set in virtualRowCount) and actual rows in `tables[0]` of dataset. I am getting the results however my pager is gone. The pager is no longer shown. How can I tell the gridview to pick up value from PagedDataSource?

Working with ASP.Net 4

Comment: please can you accept an answer on this as I don't think you're gonna see much movementon it.

Answer (score 3):

**ASP.NET 2.0+ Version**

This post here http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2008/02/09/aspnet-20-gridview-custom-sorting-with-pageddatasource/ extends the standard GridView and provides plumbing code to achieve PagedDataSource integration.

**ASP.NET 4.5 Version**

Set the AllowPaging and AllowCustomPaging attribute on the GridView as well as the Paged data source property?

```
PagedDataSource dataSource = new PagedDataSource();

int virtualRowCount = Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TotalRows"]);
dataSource.AllowCustomPaging = true;
dataSource.PageSize = 15;

dataSource.VirtualCount = virtualRowCount;
dataSource.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;

gvTaxPayerLoginDetail.AllowPaging = true; // See this line here
gvTaxPayerLoginDetail.AllowCustomPaging = true; // and this line here
gvTaxPayerLoginDetail.DataSource = dataSource;
gvTaxPayerLoginDetail.DataBind();
```

Additionally this post may also be of help http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2012/03/20/Use-Custom-Paging-in-Grid-View.aspx

Comment: Sorry missed your comment about framework version! I think the AllowPaging is present though?

Comment: Yeap, it is but for some reason the VirtualCount property is ignored

Comment: Have updated my answer with a 2.0+ version, Ill keep an eye out for a less invasive mechanism though! Also upvoted the question as its interesting! ;o)

Answer (score 1):

```
PagedDataSource dataSource = new PagedDataSource();

int virtualRowCount = Convert.ToInt32(dataset.Tables[1].Rows[0]["TotalRows"]);

dataSource.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;

dataSource.AllowCustomPaging = true;
dataSource.PageSize = 15;
dataSource.VirtualCount = virtualRowCount;
dataSource.CurrentPageIndex  =0;

gvTaxPayerLoginDetail.DataSource = dataSource;
gvTaxPayerLoginDetail.AllowPaging=True;
gvTaxPayerLoginDetail.DataBind();
```